# inject controller from different file using same module

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, module, controller

I have two files

test1.js

```
angular.module("test1",[]).controller("test1Ctrl",function(){
// some code
})
```

and

test2.js

```
angular.module("test2",[]).controller("test2Ctrl",function(){
//some code
})
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("testApp",['test1','test2']);
```

My question is  how I can inject my both controller in app.js from **test1.js** and **test2.js** using same module  and not using module test1 and test2?

Comment: What's wrong with the code in your question? There's nothing wrong with using independent modules in your app. In fact, I highly recommend it

Comment: @Phil Thanks. But is there any way to do it?

Comment: Do u mean : Using a controller from different application?
If yes - you can always use 2 ng-apps in HTML together.
and also you can use same ng-app at 2 different places

Comment: You can also look for ng-directive.
As said controllers are special directives.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep controllers in separate file then,

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("testApp",[]);
```

test1.js

```
app.controller("test1Ctrl",function(){
// some code
})
```

test2.js

```
app.controller("test2Ctrl",function(){
// some code
})
```

Finally include js files in html,

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="test1.js"></script>
<script src="test2.js"></script>
```